# reverse proxy websocket (paho) using caddy 2

Tags: mqtt, paho, caddy, caddyfile, aedes

i have an application that use PAHO.
like this:

```
  this.client = new Client(environment.ZCA_MQTT, 8888, '', '');
```

The server use Node.js with nest.js (on port 10000) and Aedes

```
    const server = require('net').createServer(aedes.handle); //(port 1883).
    and
    httpServer.listen(8888, function () {
         Logger.debug('Aedes MQTT-WS listening on port: ' + 8888)
    });
```

when i use HTTP, everything works.

I added Caddy 2 with this conf:

```
bunker.domain.io      {
#       @websockets {
#               header Connection *Upgrade*
#               header Upgrade    websocket
#       }
#       reverse_proxy @websockets 127.0.0.1:8888
#       reverse_proxy @websockets 127.0.0.1:1883
        reverse_proxy localhost
        #reverse_proxy localhost:10000
        #reverse_proxy localhost:10000

}
```

I dont know which port to redirect, and how. Can you help me a bit ?

Comment: Any chance you have found the answer yourself and can share it?